# Unable to open a file on Parse-server

Tags: android, parse-server

Can't download and retrieve file on server as well as on my app. I don't know why. on server when I double click on file, it show me 3 drop down option (download, replace and delete) when I click on download it do not download file and take me back to the role class. on real application it show me error as,

> "Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found".

when I click on download option in url it show me

> "undefined/files/3e1a47ad77bb8fbba106ff28540fe48ade43bd30/cf667b9992d81403accb38e65e61e0a6_dp.png"

I didn't understand "undefined" mean

can anyone help me that how to open and see my file on Parse server?

Comment: Can you please share the options that you are using to initialize the Parse Server? it is probably something related to the publicServerURL option.

Comment: Where are you hosted? Is it Bitnami by chance?

Comment: yes i am using Bitnami on EC2 Amazon web services